# What are the proper steps to include and use moment in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to call moment() in my Vuejs application, I've tried declaring it like so :

```
methods: {
  moment: function () {
    return moment();
  }
},
```

and tried to my test it like so :

```
beforeMount() {
    console.log(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'))
},
```

I kept getting

> [Vue warn]: Error in beforeMount hook: "ReferenceError: moment is not defined"

Do I need to add a moment to my package.json and run yarn install?

I would like to make it as light as possible since I will only need to access moment() only one page of my application, I rather not load them on all pages.

Please kindly suggest

Comment: Well, if you will use a library just once on just one page, you may not need to use it at all. And you should be importing `moment` before the component definition.

Answer (score 2):

First you should install using the following commande :

```
npm i moment --save
```

then in your component import it and use it like :

```js
import moment from 'moment/moment';

export default{

...
beforeMount() {
    console.log(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'))
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since moment is a [deprecated lib](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) (due to mutablility) also huge library in term of size , it's recommended to use other modern library sush [**dayjs**](https://day.js.org/), which is only a **2kB** fast library that offers same functionality as moment

You could install it

```
npm install dayjs --save
```

then in your project (use specific plugin days js to show your specific format `Do` )

```
import advancedFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat';

export default{

...
beforeMount() {
    dayjs.extend(advancedFormat) // use plugin
    console.log(dayjs().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'))
}
```

See sample snnipet in pure js :

```js
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_advancedFormat);

console.log(dayjs().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.10.7/dayjs.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.10.7/plugin/advancedFormat.min.js"></script>
```